# Most up to date grappling flowchart

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple

Does anyone have an up to date or something more recent than this grappling flow chart? I love this one but I'm not sure if all the rules still apply today or not, it is from 2012.

http://www.tenebraemush.net/index.php/Understanding_Grappling

Comment: Grappling Flowchart. Step 1: Don't.

Answer (score 4):

**The rules are still exactly the same.**

The rules for grappling in Pathfinder have not changed in any meaningful way since its release.  Your info from 2012 is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [this grappling walkthrough](http://www.dorkistan.com/dorkistan/PFRPG/misc/grapple.htm) that, based on the comments, dates from 2014. It goes through the grappling process step by step then summarizes what's meant by each section in plainer language.

The only difference that I can see immediately between the question's 2012 [flowchart](http://www.tenebraemush.net/index.php/Understanding_Grappling), the *d20PFSRD* 2012 [grappling Charts 1 and 2](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Grapple), and the 2014 walkthrough above is that each have different opinions on when, how often, and to whom to apply the −4 penalty for using fewer than two hands. (For more on that, see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83025/8610)).