# Maintaining one-handed grapple

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple

You take a -4 pentalty when attempting a grapple with one hand, but do you take the -4 penalty for maintaining it? Here are the relevant rules.

> - Humanoid creatures without two free hands attempting to grapple a foe take a –4 penalty on the combat maneuver roll.
> - If you do not release the grapple, you must continue to make a check each round, as a standard action, to maintain the hold.

I guess this boils down to this question: is "attempting to grapple a foe" the same as "maintaining the hold"

Comment: I think this question may be answered by answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83025/8610), although this question possibly remains distinct.

Comment: "too broad" lol, maybe he only read the title.

Comment: Can this question can be narrowed to one question to get it off hold? Or are they just too tightly linked?

Comment: part 2 is actually really easy to answer I already figured out it's a  yes, I'll just remove it

Answer (score 2):

#### This GM rules that *attempting to grapple* is different from *maintain the hold*

Here's that sentence in the context of the description of the combat maneuver [grapple](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Grapple):

> As a standard action, you can attempt to grapple a foe, hindering his combat options. If you do not have Improved Grapple, grab, or a similar ability, attempting to grapple a foe provokes an attack of opportunity from the target of your maneuver. **Humanoid creatures without two free hands attempting to grapple a foe take a –4 penalty on the combat maneuver roll.** If successful, both you and the target gain the grappled condition. If you successfully grapple a creature that is not adjacent to you,….

(Emphasis mine.) Because the sentence *both* appears alongside other information about *starting* a grapple *and* uses the phrase *attempting to grapple* as if grappling had not yet begun in earnest, this GM rules that a humanoid creature suffers that –4 penalty only initially—that is, when that humanoid tries to start the grapple—and *not* on any later grapple checks.

However, as late as [2015](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2s4x4?One-hand-free-for-grappling) this is still a point of disagreement on the Paizo messageboards. Ask your GM, or, if you're trying to avoid that penalty, just play a nonhumanoid like a typical [aasimar](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-aasimar/) or [tiefling](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-tiefling/).